# I want to show a Popup regardless of any Activity is launched. That popup has to be always on Top in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I have tried with PopupWindow Component which shows the dialog on Splash Screen but after Splash it redirects to Login Screen so I want to show the PopUp always on Top.
Regardless of any activity launched it should be in background and PopUp on Top
in Android.